# CRUD ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activeadmin

Sorry Newbie alert. I am a newbie with ROR and not a web developer.  I am having hard time understanding routes with activeadmin.
I have an exiting postgresql table with bytea column to store jpeg image and other text data.

I followed this tutorial http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=4642 .

Here is the migration file.

```
class CreateDrstests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "drstests", primary_key: "drstestid", force: true do |t|
      t.string   "serial",  limit: 10
      t.datetime "testdate"
      t.string   "result",     limit: 10
      t.string   "comment",    limit: 2000
      t.binary   "testimage"
    end
  end
end
```

Display all the data in the postgresql table as a list without the jpeg image.(working). Display individual test result with jpeg image. (Broken)

```
app/admin/drstest.rb

    ActiveAdmin.register Drstest do

       index do
         column :testtype
         column :testdate
         column :result
         default_actions
       end

       def code_image
         @image_data = Drstest.find(params[:drstestid])
         @image = @image_data.testimage
         send_data(@image, :type     => imge/jpeg,
                     :filename => @image_data.testdate,
                     :disposition => 'inline')
       end

    end

views/drstests/show.html.erb

    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <% for column in Drstest.content_columns %>
    <p>
    <b><%= column.human_name %>:</b>
    <% if column.name == "testimage" %>
      <%= image_tag("/admin/code_image/#{@drstest.drstestid }", :alt => "Image") %>
    <% else %>
      <%=h @drstest.send(column.name) %>
    <% end %>
    </p>
    <% end %>

     <%= link_to 'Back', drstests_path %>
```

Here is the error in the develoment_log

```
Started GET "/drstests/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-08 18:11:07 -0400
Processing by DrstestsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  Drstest Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "drstests".* FROM "drstests"  WHERE "drstests"."drstestid" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["drstestid", 5]]
  Rendered drstests/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 425ms (Views: 421.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started GET "/admin/code_image/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-08 18:11:08 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admin/code_image/5"):
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/share/ruby/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
  Rendered /usr/local/share/gems/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/share/gems/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/share/gems/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/share/gems/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (49.8ms)
```

Do I need to insert a custom route in routes.rb?  Pretty sure  the query is working. Just not understanding why I can not display the image.  Not sure how to debug the problem either. Any clues would be very helpful. Thank you for reading this.

Regards

Comment: add your routes file to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug the problem, you need to establish what the error is, and then work to resolve it:

---

**Error**

In any debug process, you have to start with the error:

```
(No route matches [GET] "/admin/code_image/5")
```

This error clearly states that there are no routes present for the URL you want. This means you have to consider the `config/routes.rb` file, and how you're defining the aforementioned route.

---

**Routes**

Judging from your error, you should have a routes file established as thus:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   resources :code_image #-> domain.com/admin/code_image/:id
end
```

A caveat to this is that you need to make sure you have the `code_image_controller.rb` in the correct location & defined properly:

```
#app/controllers/admin/code_image_controller.rb #-> notice the /admin folder ;)
class CodeImageController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @code_image = CodeImage.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

---

**CRUD**

Something you need to know is that when you create [CRUD routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) in Rails, using the `resources` directive, you'll get the following routes created automagically:

[image]

When you ask about creating individual routes, if you use the routes I stipulated above, you should not have an issue with the loading of a particular resource.

---

**ActiveAdmin**

Finally, just to clear up any confusion - this is meant as a debugging exercise. We don't use ActiveAdmin, and consequently, I cannot guarantee whether this solution will work with it